# Iterate through XML child of child tags in Python using elementtree

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

Unable to iterate through child tags within a child tag

have tried to find all child tags through root.iter() and iterate the same.
however the output is not generated in the hierarchy of the tags

```
for child in root.iter():
    child_tag = child.tag

    for child in root.findall('.//' + child_tag):          
        txt = "tag1/" + "tag2/" + str(child_tag) + "/" + str(child)
        print(txt)
```

Expected output:

```
tag1
tag1/tag2
tag1/tag2/tag3
tag1/tag2/tag3/tag4
tag1/tag2/tag3/tag5
tag1/tag2/tag3/tag5/tag6
```

xml file details:

```
<tag1>
    <tag2>
        <tag3>
                <tag4>         </tag4>
                <tag5>  
                    <tag6>        </tag6>      
                </tag5>
        </tag3>
    </tag2>
</tag1>
```

Output received:

```
tag1
tag1/tag2
tag1/tag2/tag3
tag1/tag2/tag3/tag4
tag1/tag2/tag3/tag5
tag1/tag2/tag5/tag6
```

--- not as per hierarchy

Comment: If you look at your print statement, you only have room for 4 tag names: tag1, tag2, str(child_tag), str(child). So your last print won't be able to have the 5 levels of hierarchy like you want. You would need to store the grandparent of the current iterated element and output those after tag1/tag2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Listing [[Python 3.Docs]: xml.etree.ElementTree - The ElementTree XML API](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#module-xml.etree.ElementTree).

Hardcoding node tags (*"tag1"*, *"tag2"*: why only those and not others?) is a sign that something is (terribly) wrong. 
Here's a simple variant that handles each *XML* node recursively.

*code00.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET


def iterate(node, path=""):
    if path:
        current_path = path + "/" + node.tag
    else:
        current_path = node.tag
    print("{0:s}".format(current_path))
    for child in node:
        iterate(child, path=current_path)


def main():
    xml_file_name = "./file00.xml"
    tree = ET.parse(xml_file_name)
    root = tree.getroot()
    iterate(root)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {0:s} {1:d}bit on {2:s}\n".format(" ".join(item.strip() for item in sys.version.split("\n")), 64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
    main()
    print("\nDone.")
```

**Output**:

> ```bat
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q057906081]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_03.07.03_test0\Scripts\python.exe" code00.py
> Python 3.7.3 (v3.7.3:ef4ec6ed12, Mar 25 2019, 22:22:05) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] 64bit on win32
>
> tag1
> tag1/tag2
> tag1/tag2/tag3
> tag1/tag2/tag3/tag4
> tag1/tag2/tag3/tag5
> tag1/tag2/tag3/tag5/tag6
>
> Done.
> ```

Comment: Thanks..... hardcoding of first two tags were because there would be present for all the nodes. I will remove the hard coding now.

Comment: a follow-up question -- how do I add the output to a dataframe ?

Comment: Hmm, I don't know. I don't know the structure of the dataframe and other such details. You could ask another question though.